# Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a USB that can also be used for Windows file storage?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning

I would like to send my nephew a 128gb thumb drive. He doesn't have a machine of his own, but I want him to be able to boot from the USB stick to Ubuntu and be able to play Minecraft on a machine he does not have the password for. Also I was thinking this would be safer because if he downloads a virus accidentally (like trying to install a mod) it would only affect the stick and not whatever hard drive is on the machine he plugs the stick into.

I was able to install Ubuntu on the USB and boot my computer with it but I would like to ask:

1) Is it possible to allocate space for the USB to Windows, so if not booting from it and you plug it in to a Windows machine, it will look like a normal USB stick with files (rather than "not formatted")

2) Is there any thing I should watch out for to ensure that he can boot with the disk on any machine?

Comment: what if he boots Ubuntu and wipes the machine he doesnt have the password for?  Is there a reason that machine is protected?

Comment: See if this can help you I may do the same when I get home. http://dopey.io/one-usb-drive-two-partitions-much-useful.html

Comment: @Keltari no particular reason for security, I suppose I just want to give him the freedom to use his own OS on any machine using the USB stick as his own even if he doesn't own a laptop

Answer (score 1):

You can format the USB drive as FAT32, which will allow for booting into Ubuntu as well as being able to use the drive within Windows for storage. A few points to bear in mind:

1. When in Windows, there will be nothing to stop the files required to boot Ubuntu from being deleted or altered. There is a risk the device could become non-bootable if a mistake is made.
2. If you wish for Ubuntu to be able to save to the drive when any changes are made, make sure you add `persistence`, otherwise you will be starting from scratch each time you boot it.
3. For optimum compatibility, you should be able to set it up in both Legacy mode (with an MBR) and EFI mode (with an EFI boot file). I've not tried it, but I believe it is possible, and that would allow for booting on both old and new hardware. Note that `Secure Boot` may prevent some installations running from USB on newer hardware. On Ubuntu this *shouldn't* be a problem, but `Secure Boot` may need to be disabled in some instances.

Comment: Do you have any more information on point #3 regarding optimum compatibility - maybe a link with steps on how to do it?

Comment: Also - I was thinking of partitioning the drive like this (32gb fat32)(98gb ext4)(8gb swap) - and then install Ubuntu on the 98gb ext4 partition, and keep the first partition at fat32 so windows can read it - but that partition would be just for files that can be shared between linux and windows. That would work too right?